Spotipy has started printing Warning of a TypeError when calling isinstance(self._session, requests.Session) upon session closure
I have a Python program that uses spotipy that has started raising a new Warning.
Both the client.Spotify and oauth2.SpotifyAuthBase Classes contain a __del__() method to ensure the connection is properly closed upon garbage collection:
def __del__(self):
    """Make sure the connection (pool) gets closed"""
    try:
        print(f'requests.Session is {requests.Session}')  # added by me for debugging
        print(f'type(requests.Session) is of type {type(requests.Session)}')  # added by me for debugging
        if isinstance(self._session, requests.Session):
            self._session.close()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

This has worked fine until now, but since yesterday has started Warning of a TypeError during final garbage collection (i.e. once all of my code has finished and exited normally):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charlierose/PycharmProjects/spotipy_release_radar/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 217, in __del__
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
Exception ignored in: <function SpotifyAuthBase.__del__ at 0x11ad1b4c0>

I added in a print statement within the try block to check what was going on (see commented out line in first code block above). During garbage collection steps during code execution (I assume whenever the requests.Session class instance is overwritten) this prints out:
requests.Session is <class 'requests.sessions.Session'>
type(requests.Session) is of type <class 'type'>

But during the final garbage collection, I get:
requests.Session is None
type(requests.Session) is of type <class 'NoneType'>

Does this mean that the class itself has somehow become None?
My code contains a ReleaseRadarCreator class and a SpotifyUser class (among others).
The __init__() method of ReleaseRadarCreator includes creation of a SpotifyUser instance.
The __init__() method of SpotifyUser includes creation of a spotipy.Spotify instance (self.spotify = Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=self.scope)))
The ReleaseRadarCreator.__init__() function also calls the spotipy.Spotify.current_user_playlists() function (via the active SpotifyUser instance).
ReleaseRadarCreator.run() then contains the bulk of the code execution, with many spotipy.Spotify function calls.
Deliberate interruption of the code (by inserting 1/0 to raise an error) inside ReleaseRadarCreator.__init__() yields the expected requests.Session is <class 'requests.sessions.Session'> and no abnormal warnings when exiting.
Code interruption any time following compeltion of ReleaseRadarCreator.__init__() (either before or or within ReleaseRadarCreator.run()) yields requests.Session is None and the accompanying isinstance() TypeError Warning.
Unsure if this is a new bug that I need to raise on the Github, or just something I'm doing wrong. Can anyone explain why this has only started happening now?

I've seen this error many times on other issues in the spotipy GitHub repo, but was never able to reproduce it myself. Normally something like requests.Session wouldn't turn itself into None, there has to be something else responsible for that.
Could you provide a minimal reproducible code?
